# When does verilog use values from the current and when from the previous timeslot?

Tags: verilog, simulation

Here is a short example code, which confused me. What is the rule to use values from the current or when from the previous simulation time-slot in verilog processes?

```
module test();

    reg clk, rst, r1, r2, r3;

    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        rst = 0;
        r1 = 0;
        r2 = 0;
        r3 = 0;

        @(posedge clk)
        rst = 1;
    end // initial

    always #5 begin : clkgen
        clk = ~clk;
    end


    /** TESTS **/

    // PREVIOUS
    always @(posedge clk) begin : proc_non_block
        r1 = rst;
    end

    // CURRENT
    always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin : proc_async
        r2 <= rst;
    end

    // PREVIOUS
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin : proc_async_neg
        r3 <= rst;
    end

endmodule // test
```

Here is the result of the simulation. (Questasim 10.4C)
[image: Sumulation result (Questasim 10.4C)]

Experiments above shows me that the current value of a given signal is used only if the given signal has an active event at the current simulation time-slot. Am I right? Any details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verilog *always* uses the current value of variable. This issue is when the current value gets updated when making an assignment. Since you wrote to `rst` with a blocking assignment in a process that unblocks on the `posedge` of `clk`, there is a race condition with other blocks that also unblock on the `posedge` of clk. There is no defined ordering of when each `always` process unblocks relative to when the `Initial` process unblocks making its assignment to `rst . So it appears as you get the _old_ value of`rst ` because the assignment has not happened yet.

The general rule is: use non-blocking assignments to a variable whenever one process writes, and another process reads the same variable and all the process are synchronized to the same clock event.

Comment: I think the result is independent on type of assignments. There would be the same result using blocking or non-blocking assignments too. (A non-blocking assignment regards only the following expression in the same block)

Comment: You are misinformed. See http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/1996-CUG-presentation_nonblocking_assigns.pdf andhttps://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece447/s13/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=synth-verilog-cummins.pdf