# Use of automatic logic variable inside a sequential procedural block--advantages?

Tags: system-verilog

In the following code for a simple inverter, an `automatic logic` variable is declared within an always_ff block and allocated using a blocking statement `_GEN = ...`

```
module Main(
  input  invert,
         CLK,
  output O0,
         O1);

  reg        Register_inst0;

  always_ff @(posedge CLK) begin
    automatic logic [1:0] _GEN;
    _GEN = {{~Register_inst0}, {Register_inst0}};
    Register_inst0 <= _GEN[invert];
  end // always_ff @(posedge)

  initial
    Register_inst0 = 1'h0;

  wire [1:0] _GEN_0 = {{~Register_inst0}, {Register_inst0}};
  assign O0 = Register_inst0;
  assign O1 = _GEN_0[invert];
endmodule
```

Does using `automatic` here have advantages for the simulation / synthesized circuit performance compared to situations where the "temporary" variable is declared outside the `always` block? An example of the latter can be found in this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/62936906/5967500 and below:

```
logic [1:0] _GEN;
always_ff @(posedge CLK) begin
    _GEN = {{~Register_inst0}, {Register_inst0}};
    Register_inst0 <= _GEN[invert];
  end // always_ff @(posedge)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference for synthesis. *Any* variable you always *write* to first and then *read* later within an `always` block gets treated as combinatorial logic. That is regardless of `always_ff` or `always_comb`.

But one exception to that rule is when that variable is read from outside the `always_ff`, it gets treated as a register, regardless of whether the *read* or *write* comes first. Declaring a variable with an `automatic` lifetime is a guarantee that variable can't be *read* outside the always.

As far as simulation performance is concerned, that is going to be very tool dependent base on how much optimization gets applied.

Comment: How about *always_ff @(posedge CLK) begin*
    `static` *logic [1:0] _GEN;*. This is supposed to be treated as a register as well, right?

Comment: @dave_59, so this means that the sensitivity list (`posedge CLK`) of the `always_ff` block is ignored for statements that are being treated as combinatorial logic? It seems the sensitivity list only has an implication on variables that are referred to outside the block.

Comment: @Serge No, it does not matter where the variable gets declared, or its lifetime. Only how it gets used matters to synthesis.
@rkshthrmsh No. The `@(posedge clk)` means _some_ of the logic is sequential. _Some_ can be combinatorial as well.